# Why is excel.button not shown in the object browser?

Tags: excel, vba

In an Excel VBA project, I am able to define and use objects whose type is `excel.button`:

```
 dim btn as excel.button
 set btn = activeSheet.buttons.add(...)
```

After declaring such a variable, I can use intellisense to see a button's properties and methods.

However, when going to the object browser (F2), I am unable to find any entry for this button class nor do  I find any mention on Microsoft's object model documentation for Excel.

So, what is so special about this button class and where do I find its documentation?

Comment: Does [this](https://superuser.com/questions/637428/how-can-i-view-the-properties-of-a-button-on-an-excel-worksheet) help

Comment: This link does not seem to have anything to do with VBA or a type library.